# Auto-populate Account name Field on Contact Level

Tags: apex, trigger

I am pretty new to the APEX/Triggers so any help is appreciated;

I have a custom field on the Contact object called 'Email Domain'.  I am adding new Contacts that don't have Account Name.

What I would like to do is, when the Email Domain on one Contact matches another, the Account Name should match as well.

For Example
I have:

Name:John Wayne
Account Name: Wayne Enterprise
Email Domain: abcinc.com

IF
Name: Peter Don
Account Name: (blank)
Email Domain: abcinc.com

Then for Contact Peter Don then Account Name = Wayne Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

This can get you started, then once you have a more specific question we can help you better

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

Trailhead also has many tutorials

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works fine for me. 
You can Use this code :

```
trigger populateAccountNameOnEmaildomain on Contact (after insert,after update) {
    map<string,Id> map1 = new map<string,Id>();
         List<Contact> contList3 = new List<Contact>();
         Set<String> emailList = new Set<String>();
         for(Contact con : trigger.new) {
             if(con.Emaildomain__c != null && con.AccountId == null) {
                 contList3.add(con);
                 emailList.add(con.Emaildomain__c);
             }
         }
        List<Contact> contList = [SELECT Emaildomain__c,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Emaildomain__c IN : emailList AND AccountId != NULL];
        for(Contact con:contList){
            map1.put(con.Emaildomain__c,con.AccountId);
    }
         List<Contact> newConList = new List<Contact>();
            for(Contact con:contList3){
                if(map1.get(con.Emaildomain__c) != NULL) {
                    Contact con1 = new Contact(Id = con.Id);
                    con1.AccountId= map1.get(con.Emaildomain__c);
                    newConList.add(con1);
                }

            }                   
            update newConList;
}
```

Regards,

Ajay

Comment: This works well on the Sandbox, but in Production i am getting the following error when I do a Insert using Data Loader or Import Wizard

populateAccountNameOnEmaildomain: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I think you are trying to update too much Accounts (more than 100000), so the error is coming. To avoid this error you have to use Batch Class.